# How to restrict SQL server profiler to show my symmetric key password while executing query from C# code?

Tags: sql-server-2008, profiler

I used symmetric encryption to encrypt sensitive data in my application. I don't want anyone see my password for decrypting the data. But system admin can able to see symmetric password in SQL Server Profiler.

How can I stop them ?

**Profiler Result :**

```
exec sp_executesql N' OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = ''admin@123'' ;
```

Comment: If you don' trust your system admin not to snoop around, hire a new one that you do.

Comment: @vonPryz to name one example: Having your database hosted somewhere in a 3rd party cloud.

Comment: @EdwardDortland The question boils down to trust. A sysadmin has lots of ways to steal secrets ranging from physical access to protocol analysis. Valuable and sensitive data into cloud belongs not.

Answer (score 3):

Don't execute the statement as a string by using `sp_executesql`

Execute the statement directly:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = 'admin@123'
```

That way, SQL Server is able to parse the statement and will notice that it's a command that contains sensitive information and will not show it in any trace output.

it will show up as:

```
--*OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY----------------------------
```

Please be aware that this applies to ALL statements that contain passwords. So also when you create the keys.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did not use "sp_executesql" to execute my query from c# code. Please find below my c# code "OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default WITH PASSWORD = ''admin@123''; select CONVERT(varchar(max),DecryptByKey(UniqueNumber)) from employeeTable;CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default; ". But the sql profiler return the result like that.

Comment: Update your question with the relevant C# code. Including how you open the connection, which (if applicable) Data access layer you are using . Your question might get migrated to another stackexchange but lets first see the code.

Comment: @vijay You need to show the C# part of your code too. Likely it is the one that sends SQL statements to sp_executesql.

Comment: //Creating query.
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append(" OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY asym_RegAna_Default  WITH PASSWORD = 'admin@123' ; ");
query.Append(" select CONVERT(varchar(max),DecryptByKey(UniqueIdentificationNumber)) as DecryptedNumber  from EmployeePersonalDetailsTable ");
query.Append("; CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY sym_RegAna_Default;");
fetchQuery.SelectCondition = query;               
DBAccess dbAccess = new DBAccess(getConnectionStringName());
dbDataReader = dbAccess.ExecuteReader(fetchQuery);

Comment: @vijay Do you understand that definitions for fetchQuery and DBAccess would be quite important in this context?

Comment: "fetchQuery and DBAccess", these two are my internal framework methods.so i cant modify it. could you please tell me How to run this query as SQL commands in c# ?

Comment: @vijay Read the framework's docs or ask your boss. There are ways to bypass the internal framework, but surely you need to discuss with project management about such an approach.

Comment: This query executed with type "cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text". I need to change this type ? which type i have to use to execute this query from c# ?