# Disable the SQL profiler to be executed on particular query running from ASP.NET application

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, profiler

I have set of queries executing from an ASP.NET application and I don't want those SQL queries to be traced by SQL Server Profiler. How can I do it?

Comment: Is that this query by any chance? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55652/how-to-restrict-sql-server-profiler-to-show-my-symmetric-key-password-while-exec/

Comment: So you didn't ask the framework team how to change query type?

Comment: The question is: Why do you want the queries to be hidden from Profiler?

Comment: This is the query that is using symmetric key with password for security purpose.i don't want anyone to profile my query and view the password.

Comment: Okay, so it is in fact still the same problem you are trying to solve as the link I gave in the first comment. Unfortunately, you can't "disable" profiler, and certainly not on a per query basis. Even if you could, any DBA could undo it. That's not the way to go. You need to solve your original problem (see first comment). To do that, I was kind enough to post a question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885953/prevent-ado-net-from-using-sp-execute-for-security-reason. Lets see what that brings us.